# Подскажите аналог multiset из C++ для PascalABC

Tags: pascal, структуры-данных

В C++ есть контейнер set и multiset, которые добавляют элементы в порядке возрастания. Подскажите, есть ли такое в PascalABC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вообще то в паскале множества (тип set) существовали испокон веков. И [PascalABC](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/Types/sets.html) не исключение. Более того, тип "встроен" в язык и некоторые вещи являются заметно удобнее (как мне кажется) - добавление/удаление/проверка наличия делаются "естественными" способами.

Также, PascalABC использует классы с .NET и поэтому доступны `HashSet<T>` и `SortedSet<T>` - [ссылка на документацию](http://pascalabc.net/downloads/pabcnethelp/index.htm?page=LangGuide/PABCSystemUnit/Files/Standard%20types.html) - правда ничего детальнее я не нашел.